# Axis config - thousand separators and title direction

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm trying to make my chart look nice. However, I don't seem to find the way to:
   - plot the thousand separator
   - to make the Y axis 'GWP' look straight

I have read other threat of related issues, but nothing seem to work. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the code and attached is a picture of how the chart looks so far:

```
ggplot(BUSINESS, aes(fill=Business, y=GWP, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73","Darkblue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,3500000,500000), limits = c(0,3500000)) + 
  theme_ipsum() +
  ggtitle('GWP development') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=14, family="Calibri", face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=11, family="Calibri", face="bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(hjust=1, size=10, family="Calibri", face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size=11, family="Calibri"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust=1, size=10, family="Calibri", face="bold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by making the y-axis look straight. But here is an example that includes comma formatting for the y-axis, scales the numbers down (using the `scale = 1/1000` argument), and adds decimal places.

The y-axis label is also rotated (with the `angle=0` argument).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

df <- tribble(
  ~country, ~gwp,
  "Brasil", 1000000,
  "Argentina", 2500000,
  "Uruguay", 200000
)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(country, gwp)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(scale = 1/1000, accuracy = .1)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(y = "GWP (000)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for your help, ravic_!